# What Does the Cell Value in a Composite Raster Mean?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

When I make a composite raster in QGIS using the GRASS r.composite tool and then click on a certain cell I get these values in the blue/green/red/composite rasters:
blue = 124
green = 124
red = 172
composite = 15861.

I know that the blue/green/red represent the brightness values of the given bands. What does the 15861 represent and how is it calculated?

Comment: It's likely an integer value representing the alpha composite: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jfc/ch04_07.htm

Comment: What version of QGIS and Grass are you using?  Also, please state your settings as they impact the operation (and therefore calculation of r.composite). Interestingly, I consistently only get RGB and no composite band in 2.4.

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.2 on Windows 7 with the GRASS 6.4.3 GUI. For settings, I am using 32 for number of values for red, green, and blue. The tutorial that I am using is the FOSS4G Academy course on Remote Sensing. The tutorial document is at http://foss4geo.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/module-3-lab2.pdf.

Comment: Please, read the manual for [r.composite](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.composite.html). If you use the "default" intensity levels for each component (that is 32), you should get slightly different RGB values compared to the "input" RGB. You may want to use [r.what](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.what.html) with the `-r` parameter (`Output color values as RRR:GGG:BBB`) to query a cell's RGB combination. Also to look at [r.what.color](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.what.color.html). [Links to GRASS6, as this is the version the OP uses].

Comment: Check also this thread: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2015-January/071739.html.

Answer (score 2):

The number 124 as a binary byte (eight digits) is 01111100.  To represent an RGB triple of three bytes would require three times eight, or 24, such bits.  By default, `r.composite` reduces this to just 15 bits by discarding the least significant bits in each band.  Thus, it trims 01111100 to 01111, which is 15.  (Equivalently, it divides 124 by 8 and ignores the remainder.)  Apparently these three five-bit results are concatenated in the order B, G, R to form a 15-bit number (representing values between 0 and 2^15-1 = 32767, which is small enough to keep the color table to a manageable size).  **These values therefore represent three image bands, each with just five bits of precision rather than the original eight.**

In the example of the question, **the calculations proceed like this:**

1. Blue = 124 is converted to 124/8 = 15 (plus a neglected remainder of 4).  In binary this is 01111.
2. Green = 124 is converted to 124/8 = 15 (plus a neglected remainder of 4). In binary this is 01111.
3. Red = 172 is converted to 172/8 = 21 (plus a neglected remainder of 4).  In binary this is 10101.
4. The digits are concatenated into 01111 01111 10101.  This 15-digit binary number represents the value 15861 = (15*32 + 15)*32 + 21.

`r.composite` may do more processing than this, and it may do it slightly differently depending on the options you supply, but these operations do show the basic way in which a byte can be converted to a five-bit value.

**You can approximately reverse the procedure** using successive divisions by 32:

1. 15861/32 = 495 plus a remainder of 21.  (Multiplied by 8, this remainder of 21 gives 168, which is only a little bit less than the original 172 for the red band.)
2. 495/32 = 15 plus a remainder of 15.  (Multiplied by 8, this remainder of 15 gives 120, which is only a little bit less than the original 124 for the green band.)
3. We are left with 15, which when multiplied by 8 gives 120, which is only a little bit less than the original 124 for the blue band.

#### Reference

`r.composite` manual page at https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.composite.html.